# CodenameOne - Build hint with injected plist values for XCode does not make it through the build process

Tags: java, xcode, maven, codenameone, plist

I am using CodenameOne to have the iOS<14 counterpart of my Android and my Swift iOS 14 apps.

In the CodenameOne build system I put the following injection of plist values:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key><array> <dict><key>UTTypeDescription</key><string>List of datatype</string><key>UTTypeConformsTo</key><array><string>public.json</string><string>public.database</string><string>public.data</string><string>public.text</string><string>public.content</string></array><key>UTTypeIdentifier</key><string>com.myapp.datatype</string><key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key><dict><key>public.filename-extension</key><array><string>ext</string></array><key>public.mime-type</key><array><string>application/json</string> </array> </dict> </dict> </array>
```

They should be found in the resulting XCode project that is built.

But in my case those values are not replicated in the XCode project, indeed they do not make it through the maven build process (the features are also missing in the app when running in the iOS simulator, for instance, the custom extension association).

Other build hints are correctly found in the final XCode project as expected, in the .plist file corresponding to the main app (I can open it in XCode).

Is that injected plist string of values wrong?

What can be done to have it replicated inside the XCode project or fix it?

Comment: Did you use the correct casing? `ios.plistInject` ?

Comment: @Shai Almog I have ios.plist_inject as you suggested in a past thread on another discussion platform. I guess it was a typo or it has changed since then. I also have android.xintent_filter, is it wrong too?

Comment: I wrote `ios.plistInject` not `ios.plist_inject`